# show online if user views my page and show offline if he closes

Tags: php

i am sending my customer a url of my specific page , i need a indication that whether he is online or offline in my page. there is no problem of multi-users,its a page that can be viewed by only one user at a time.

i tried unsetting the session on browser close it won't works

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["firstname"] = "Peter";
$_SESSION["lastname"] = "Parker";

echo 'Hi, ' . $_SESSION["firstname"] . ' ' . $_SESSION["lastname"];

session_destroy();
```

i expect the online status of this page on my dashboard page

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript, and perhaps websockets, if you want to monitor access in real-time.

Comment: please research on how to do that online, as it requires a lot more than what you have. On backend and DB level, you have to store session data including last activity of users and you have to set up cookies for the browser. Then you have to use some techniques to make the check instant like ajax or websocket

Comment: its completed thanks, i used to take time stamps and do the query in a regular time interval.